# Using a web browser to generate a gallery/slideshow from local files

Tags: shell-script, chrome, image-manipulation, javascript

I'm trying to see how far I can go with using a web browser for various tasks vs. native apps. One of these tasks is selecting a group of local image files and generate a preview/gallery/slideshow in a web browser.

Ideally (and conceivably) the web page could be generated with just Javascript and HTML, therefore not requiring a local webserver to run (in order to minimize system load). Or, to keep things 'fun' - it would be cool to keep everything in the javascript would by running any server-side code with a node.js solution.

One could use a custom script in Thunar or Nautilus, for example, to pass the names of the files to a script that would load the images into a web browser.

Does anybody know of a solution like this (or any other 'clever' local webview/web app solutions)?

ps. I'm currently using Xubuntu 15.10 (and loving it!)